# How to allocate same yes no buttons to different functions

Tags: javascript, function, button

I have two yes no buttons that i wish to use at different stages of the program for different functions.
As they are linked to one function

```
  <input type="button" value="Yes" class="yes" onclick="*choice1(1)*;" />
  <input type="button" value="No" class="no" onclick="*choice1(0)*;" />
```

how can i make them useful for other functions as well, so i would not need more redundant buttons.

Im trying to create an interactive story. That at different stages there is a choice to make between two options. I am using an if else method, which makes it hard as far as i understand to designate a button to a function - because each function uses two options each time.

Here is the code (thank you very much:):

```
       <script type="text/javascript">
        var photo = "photo";
        var edgar = "edgar"
        var x;

        function choice1(x){            
        if (x == 1)
        {
       document.getElementById("photo").src = "images/dragon1.jpg";
       document.getElementById("stage1").innerHTML = "Once upon a time  
       there was a dragon";
       setTimeout("choice2()",5*1000);

      }   
       else if (x == 0)
        { 
       document.getElementById("photo").src = "images/sea.jpg";
       document.getElementById("stage1").innerHTML = "Would you like to  
       listen to some music?";
       document.getElementById("edgar").play();
        }
    } 
     function choice2(x){

      document.getElementById("photo").src = "images/dragon9.jpg";
      document.getElementById("stage1").innerHTML = "Was he a friendly 
      dragon?";

     if (x == 1)
      {document.getElementById("photo").src = "images/dragon2.jpg";
       document.getElementById("stage1").innerHTML = "He had many 
     friends and he liked to party";
    }
    else if (x == 0)
    { document.getElementByID ("photo").src = "images/dragon3.jpg";
      document.getElementById("stage1").innerHTML = "He spent his days 
    thinking about the wrongs of the world";
    }   
    }

    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <table align="center">
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2" align="center" width="800" height="300"><img 
        id="photo" width="800" height="300"></td>

        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2" align="center" width="800" height="100"><h1 
    id="stage1">Would you like to read a story?</h1></td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="center" width="400" height="200"><input type="button" 
    value="Yes" class="yes" onclick="choice1(1);" /></td>
        <td align="center" width="400" height="200"><input type="button" 
    value="No" class="no" onclick="choice1(0);" /></td>
    </tr> 
    </table>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Remove the inline handlers, and use proper event attaching method instead. Then you've a couple of alternatives, you can add several listeners, or remove the old listener, and add a new at an appropriate stage of program flow, or in single handler, determine where to redirect the execution depending on the situation. If you would explain with more details, how you would use the buttons, and posibbly show some code examples, we might be able to help better.

Comment: Now we can see your problem. Actually it's not about reusing buttons, rather it's a question about data structure you need. Your story is like a tree, and every question creates two more branches to the tree. The problem is, that this is growing really fast, after ten questions you will have hundred answers with their images and texts (10^2). You can't store this amount within functions called by an `if..else` structure. You'll need a data structure to store the texts and image paths (and flags whether to continue or not?), and control flow to show the data for every stage correctly.